# codeigniter 4 Подключение сторонней библиотеки

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

как в Codeigniter 4 подключить стороннюю библиотеку? в частности PHPExcel. в CI 3 было достаточно кинуть его в папку libraries  и сделать `$this->load->library('PHPExcel')`.
Сейчас всё так же расположено в папке libraries.
Пытаюсь через `use App\Libraries\PHPExcel` выходит ошибка что класс не найден.
Пытаюсь через include,require, require_once уже ошибка что не найден контроллер
при работе следующей строки

```
$excel= new PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->excel = new PHPExcel();
```

Из инструкции по переходу с 3.x на 4.x
**Libraries**

- Your app classes can still go inside app/Libraries, but they don’t have to;
- Instead of CI3’s `$this->load->library(x);` you can now use `$this->x = new X();`, following namespaced conventions for your component